# Http maximum GET/POST query parameters supported

Tags: http, url, browser, limit

I read many questions about the limit of the URL in HTTP still not able to find the answer to how many parameters are maximum supported in HTTP

What is the maximum number of parameters supported in HTTP by parameters i mean:

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=cookies&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8
```

Here there are 3 parameters:

**q ie oe** and their corresponding values.

Answer (score 1):

The query string is under authority of [RFC 3986, section 3.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4) which does not specify any limit with the exception of the allowed characters. You will also struggle to find any limitation on the logical number of parameters, since there has never been a real specification on the format; what you find in there is rather a best-practice that has been highly influenced by what CGI is doing. So the number of parameters is very much bound by what the client or server is willing to transfer/accept (the lower bound wins, obviously). Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812925/what-is-the-maximum-possible-length-of-a-query-string), you can find a rough estimate [here](https://boutell.com/newfaq/misc/urllength.html).

Answer (score 0):

There is no limit for parameters number, its all about data size how many KBs you are sending using your GET request, however this value is configurable from web server side (Apache, Tomact, ..etc).

The default limit for the length of the request line is 8190 bytes in apache and this value could be changed to increase it or decrease it.